# Get the text value of OCI-LOB in PHP

Tags: php, oracle

I have a column in the DB which is of type `CLOB` and I can't get the value in PHP as it is shown as

> "resource id='204' type='"oci8 descriptor"'".

My adapter code:

```
 $this->_db->fetchRow(
                    $this->_db->select()
                        ->from(self::TABLE_NAME, array(
                            'BODY'
                        ))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is covered in [The Underground PHP and Oracle Manual](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html), page 234 "Fetching LOBs". Here's the example from that page:

```
<?php
$c = oci_connect('hr', 'welcome', 'localhost/XE');

$myblobid = 123;

$query = 'select blobdata from mybtab where blobid = :myblobid';
$s = oci_parse($c, $query);
oci_bind_by_name($s, ':myblobid', $myblobid);
oci_execute($s);
$arr = oci_fetch_array($s, OCI_ASSOC);
if (is_object($arr['BLOBDATA'])) { // protect against a NULL LOB
    $data = $arr['BLOBDATA']->load();
    $arr['BLOBDATA']->free();
    echo $data;
}
?>
```

I would advise reading the manual page yourself as there is important advice about avoiding memory leaks and returning LOB data as a string.

Comment: That did the trick for me, I don't understand why Oracle always has weird ways to do some things. Anyway hands up for the link to the guide! _o/